# Media Manager js Error - custom plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x

There is this content builder:
http://innovastudio.com/builderdemo/example1.html

I am working on a plugin for FLEXIcontent to implement it. I'm trying to call the media modal.

In the javascript of a contentbuilder plugin in J3.4.5 - it requires the hardcoded URL of the media manager eg:

```
imageselect: images.html
```

Now - I have tried to access the image media with:

```
imageselect: "<?php echo $base; ?>administrator/index.php?option=com_media&view=images&tmpl=component&e_name=imageurl&return_url=1"
```

This creates a popup that shows the media manager - and I am able to upload the image. However I get a js error when I select the image to insert:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.parent.jInsertEditorText is not a function in popup-imagemanager.js:136
```

[image: Problem]

What do I need to do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear: The jInsertEditorText javascript function is not available in the parent window (= the page from where you call the popup). This seems - guessing from the name - to be the function that is responsible from getting your selected image from the popup into your editor(?). Without further information (e.g. what is "a contentbuilder plugin" or what do you even want to achieve) I can only advise you to make sure that function is included.

Comment: Sorry - http://innovastudio.com/builderdemo/example1.html is an example of what I am trying to build- I think its because it uses a different way to pull up modals - not Joomla "modal".